# Static IP problem

Tags: networking, kali-linux

I want to have a static IP for this Kali linux 2016.2 system. I couldn't get it to work so far:

First up, I tried editing `/etc/network/interfaces` in which I added the following:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.30
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

I changed my local IP to 192.168.0.30, but as weird as it might be: I couldn't access the internet. So I edited it back to the original and began to search for answers online.

I've also tried this:

[image: screenshot]

which unfortunately didn't work either.

**What is happening? How can I get my system to have a static IP of my choice?**

I would highly appreciate any kind of help.

EDIT: I am running Kali Linux in vmbox

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use /etc/network/interfaces then just uninstall or disable network-manager

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a little more on how exactly that should be done?